# How to move a label in native script using CSS?

Tags: css, vue.js, nativescript, native

i am trying to move the label around the page but it's not moving at all.

This is the code:

```
<Label text="Hello" class="hello" @tap='hello' />
```

CSS Code:

```
 .hello{
outline: none;                  
height: 55px;                   
color:black;                  
width:400px;
top:50px;
left:30px;
}
```

Comment: also set `position: absolute` (or relative, if it should be relative to some other elemetn)

Comment: This isn't enough information to help you with your issue. What EXACTLY do you want to achieve. "It's not moving, I want to move it", doesn't help anyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
.hello{
    outline: none;                  
    height: 55px;                   
    color:black;                  
    width:400px;
    position:fixed;  /* add */
    top:50px;
    left:30px;
}
```

Comment: {N} does not support position attribute. It depends on parent layout, for absolute positioning you have to make sure the parent layout is absolute layout. Otherwise use margin / horizontal alignment attributes to move it.